# ScrollView background touch keyboard will not go down in ipad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

i have added the scrollview on the page when we click on the background the keyboard will not go down what can i do .Please any can help me or give some reference or tutorial.thanks in advance.

```
     -(IBAction)backGroundTouch
      {
         [txtUserName resignFirstResponder];

         [txtFirstName resignFirstResponder];

         [txtLastName resignFirstResponder];

         [txtNickName resignFirstResponder];

        [txtDisplayName resignFirstResponder];
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the keyboard on touching the scrollview means use the UIResponder delegate api for touches.

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

Resign first responder for all the text fields in this api.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: What does `touchesBegan:withEvent:` have to do with resigning first responder?

Comment: The textfield resign responder can be called in the touchesBegan api. Since, UIScrollview inherits from UIResponder, you can remove the keyboard from the touches event.

Answer (score 1):

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer   shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
  {

  if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]] )
  {
     [textfield resignFirstResponder];
  }

  return TRUE;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Go through Following Steps-

1. In .h file
2. Set delegate to all textfields.
3. in tabGuesterRecognizer: method -
   check if the point is not in all fields or any other object  then

   [textfield resignFirstResponder];

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your `backGroundTouch` method gets called?

By the way, there is no need to call `resignFirstResponder` on each `UITextView` or `UITextField`, you can resign any first responder using `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];`.

This code will work for you:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: When we implement this code ,Does not responsed any thing help another refrence or tutorial.thanks in advance.